# Xubuntu 16.04 freezes during login after new nvidia driver install

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, xubuntu

Xubuntu 16.04
Nvidia Geforce 1050

I have drivers Nvidia-384, some time ago decided to change to new ones - 390. After reboot Xubuntu freezed after I typed password during entering. There is only a wallpaper, and mouse coursor (moves).

Strangely, when I login as 'Guest' everything works.

So I changed it back to old 384 driver.

Also, everytime when I login, there is a error named "xorg crashed with sigabrt in osabort()". Do you think it's smh connected?